# Examples disappeared from a topic request

Tags: bug, documentation

Last friday I created new examples for a topic request (Interfaces and inheritance with JAXB in JAXB topic) I actually clicked the Create Topic and then went on to create an example. Which I later edited a bit to correct some typos. Which I later edited again to add another example that I thought pertinent but different enough from the first one to deserve it's own place.

I also wrote an example for an existing topic that needed improvement, namely [Introduction to JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jaxb/4616/introduction-to-jaxb#t=20160906164117009202). A hello world of sorts to generate code from XSD.

Today (tuesday) I log on to find some tidbit of rep from that hello world example, which I check. And then I go on to check the others to find them gone. Disappeared without a trace, the topic back to "uncreated" state with no draft or anything. The topic request is still present in exactly the same state it was before I wrote the two examples for it.

What happened?

Comment: `I actually clicked the Create Topic and then went on to create an example. Which I later edited a bit to correct some typos.`, second this